# How bad are huge php files?

Tags: php, optimization, service

I have a web site without any nessasery functions and a big Php file (over 13000 lines) on another server (it is using by web and mobile app), where all the logic functions was placed separated by classes, but most of the functions are in one class (11000 lines).
Size of the whole file is 1282KB.

How bad is that for the execution time?

On the server the sing in process takes less than a second, but on my much weaker PC (i5 3470 3.2GHz; 8GB RAM) it takes 10-15 seconds independent on size of data stream. An anomaly low speed in my opinion.

Is this file the biggest problem, that slowing processes so hard, or should i search the Problem somewhere else?

Comment: over 13000 lines is crazy, are you sure every function belongs to that class?

Comment: I'm sure most of them can be placed anywhere else, but due to lack of time all functions were thrown there...
anyway, I have to make sure that this is the problem  before I start changing something.

Comment: This is one time when the comment *Please include the code* is probably not a good idea. :-/

Comment: @ИльяФеллер as painful as it is - I think that's the best starting foot. I mean each time you call that file, you're loading over 10k lines. Most files should barely go over 1000. I see 1000 line files and get scared.